# Android TTS sound breaking

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have developed a TTS based application. When playing it sound, if any other notification triggered, then TTS playing with sound breaking. (Ex: if SMS received TTS sound breaks)
What are condition under which such an issue can occur?

Answer (score 2):

there is a bug in the Android API < 8. To restore the original sound, just say "nothing".

```
 protected void speak(final String text, final int mode) {
    speechParams.clear();
    speechParams.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, 
                              String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
    engine.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, speechParams);
    //Bug with API level < 8: The original sound isn't restored automatically.
    //So we do it by speaking nothing. 
    speechParams.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            this.engine.speak("", mode, speechParams);
        }       
    }
```

Hope that helps.